# Splitting sentences with nltk while preserving quotes

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, nltk

I am using nltk to split a text into sentence units. However, I need the sentences that contain quotes to be extracted as a single unit. Right now each sentence, even if it is within a quote is getting extracted as a separate part.

This is an example of something that I am trying to extract as a single unit:

```
"This is a sentence. This is also a sentence," said the cat.
```

Right now I have this code:

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

text = 'This is a sentence. This is also a sentence," said the cat.'

print '\n-----\n'.join(tokenizer.tokenize(text, realign_boundaries=True))
```

This works pretty well, but I want to maintain sentences with quotes in them even when the quotes themselves contain multiple sentences.

The code above produces:

```
This is a sentence.
-----
This is also a sentence," said the cat.
```

I am trying to get that whole text extracted as a single unit:

```
"This is a sentence. This is also a sentence," said the cat.
```

Is there an easy way to do this with nltk or should I use regex instead? I was impressed with how easy it was to get started with nltk, but am stuck now.

Comment: Which tokenizer are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, then this regex should do it:

```
import re

text = '"This is a sentence. This is also a sentence," said the cat.'

for grp in re.findall(r'"[^"]*\."|("[^"]*")*([^".]*\.)', text):
    print "".join(grp)
```

It's a combination of 2 patterns or'd together. The first one finds ordinary quoted sentences. The second finds ordinary sentences or sentences with a quotation followed by a period. If you have  more complex sentences it may need some further adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your print statement to this:

```
print ' '.join(tokenizer.tokenize(text, realign_boundaries=True))
```

This will join the sentences with a space instead of `\n-----\n`.

Comment: the point is to split sentences in the text except those that are in quotes. `' '.join` would join all sentences in/outside quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to clarify the question a bit. I hope it makes more sense now.