# Python3 - Getting quoted text with spaces as single item

Tags: list, python-3.x, input, quotes

If I have a input line such as

```
userInput = input("Enter stuff: ").split()
```

which returns a list split by spaces.

How would I go about getting this to keep quoted text as a single item in the list?

eg. If I input `hello "where are you?"`

I want to get a list with `['hello', 'where are you?']` instead of `['hello', '"where', 'are', 'you?"']`

Currently I am using a for loop to add the quoted text back together but I was hoping for a sleeker way.

```
userInputString = ""
for x in userInput[1:]:
    userInputString = userInputString + x + " "
userInputString = userInputString[1:-2] #remove the quotes and the last space
```

Comment: There are a few options for this including using a regex or for loop over list and build a second data structure that looks for double quotes for linking words - what have you tried?

Comment: Ahh, I was using a for loop to put the quoted text back together but was hoping for a sleeker way. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: Honestly, this question is pretty broad (there are a lot of methods for doing this): beyond the for loop [two are shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933532/splitting-sentences-with-nltk-while-preserving-quotes)

Comment: Just added the current method that works for me, the input will only be a single world followed by the quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
>>> s = 'hello "where are you?"'
>>> s.split('"')
['hello ', 'where are you?', '']
```

And to avoid last empty space, better use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [item for item in s.split('"') if item]
['hello ', 'where are you?']
```

Comment: Try that with the string: `s = 'hello? "how are you" I am "fine thank you"'` you'll note it also combines "I am"

Comment: `s = 'hello foo "what do you want?" pies "I love cheese"'` will also break it.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand correctly the question. What result should I get with this string:

`'hello? "how are you" I am "fine thank you"'`

?

Comment: you should end up with `[hello?, how are you, I, am, fine thank you]`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to use shell style splitting, which is quote sensitive:

```
>>> s = 'hello "where are you?"'
>>> shlex.split(s)
['hello', 'where are you?']
```